# curl "Unknown SSL protocol error in connection" error in server, but works on local

Tags: php, curl, ssl

I'm trying to retrieve data from a site (i've censored the url) with this code:

```
<?php 

  $url = [doesnt really matter];

  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

  $archivo_xml = fopen("test.tst", "w");

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE,$archivo_xml);

  curl_exec($ch);
  $as1 = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_NAMELOOKUP_TIME);
  $as2 = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONNECT_TIME);
  $as3 = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_PRETRANSFER_TIME);
  $as4 = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_STARTTRANSFER_TIME);
  $as5 = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME);

  echo "Lookup: ",$as1," \n\r Connect: ",$as2," \n\r Pretransfer: ",$as3," \n\r Starttransfer: ",$as4," \n\r Total: ",$as5,"\n\r","Error: ", curl_error($ch), "\n\r";

  curl_close($ch);
  fclose($archivo_xml);

?>
```

It work's fine on local but not in the server. Here's the output from local:

```
Lookup: 0.015155 
 Connect: 0.0281 
 Pretransfer: 0.129087 
 Starttransfer: 0.786341 
 Total: 0.786384
Error:
```

and here's the output from the server:

```
Lookup: 0.028731 
 Connect: 0.043182 
 Pretransfer: 0 
 Starttransfer: 0 
 Total: 60.057787
Error: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to [censored url]
```

With any other url works just fine, the problem is with this specific one.

localhost PHP version: 5.4.23

server PHP version: 5.5.7

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the output of verbose option?

Comment: from command line: http://pastebin.com/KPxMzu3N

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SOLVED**. Because of this known bug http://sourceforge.net/p/curl/bugs/1319/ I downgraded curl to 7.33 and it worked.

Comment: How can I downgrade curl to previous version?

Comment: @Umair it depends on the OS you're working on. In any linux distro you should use the package manager, like apt-get in debian/ubuntu or yum in fedora/centos. However, as this issue is 3 years old, I strongly recommend you not to downgrade cURL unless it's necessary.

Answer (score 17):

Try setting **`cURL`** param

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3); // Apparently 2 or 3
```

Answer (score 2):

As in the case of this post adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);` did not immediately resolve the issue today the SSL has been re-validated and accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation with the same error. 
Using a constant like this made it work:

```
curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 'CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3' );
```

Researched link: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1364

Other constants:
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSLVERSION.html

Answer (score 0):

Try with both options

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

If still not working then URL might be blocked on your server.

Comment: Are you able to ping that url from the server?